# Used MaxDegreeOfParallism for parallel foreach, sometimes stops process in between

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel.foreach

There is a long running process which I'm running in `Parallel.ForEach` with `MaxDegreeOfParallism = 3`. Sometimes my process stops in between.

For example, there is 150 documents which should be process and after 100 successful document process is stopped. Is this can be other user parallel hitting application and it takes memory? Does IIS automatically kills the process if any memory issue? Does this happened because of memory issue? Looks like the server has memory.

Please suggest.

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is *meant* to use all available cores to process a lot of data, by partitioning the data and feeding each partition to a worker task. It's *not* meant for asynchronous operations or launching a lot of tasks at once. As for ASP.NET terminating a long operation, yes, that's the default behavior *and* a good thing. Otherwise a bug could easily cause the server to freeze eg in an infinite loop

Comment: There are two questions here - how to perform long tasks in ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core, and how to process lots of documents. Post what you actually want to do, not how you thought it could be solved.

Comment: For long running tasks in ASP.NET, check Scott Hanselman's [How to run background tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). ASP.NET Core makes this a lot easier for simple cases with [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) but options like Hangfire or Coravel are better if you need to create multiple types of background jobs

Comment: Beyond that, you'll have to explain what you actually want to do. You could create a job that processes documents from one big list, 3 at a time, eg using ActionBlock. Or you could create a queue that receives documents as they're posted and processes them  in the background. Perhaps the job needs to poll some document source? Or not?

Comment: Actually i want to do process documents from one big list few at a time asynchronously. each document will take up to 30 minutes of time to complete. some how this process stop in between. how i can overcome from this issue? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: You haven't posted any code so it's impossible to guess what's wrong. If you try to perform such jobs in response to a web request, the request will time out after a while and get aborted. That's why you need to use the techniques posted in the articles I posted in the comments

Comment: Thanks mate. I have used hangfire and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have used hangfire in order to resolve the issue.
https://www.hangfire.io/